# Children's book series where three siblings fight an electricity-based alien race with weapons built by their dad

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I'm trying to find the name of a series I read as a kid. There were at least two or three books in the series, in which siblings discover that the Earth is being infiltrated by an alien race that is composed of electricity, or can take over electrical devices.

I don't remember if their scientist dad was captured from the beginning, but at some point, he was abducted, and a big part of the goal was to find him. He was also the brain behind the only weapons capable of harming the aliens; probably why he was a target.

I'm going to guess it was published in the late 90s or early 2000s. I read the books between 1997 and 2002.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year/s did you read these books and when do you think they might've been published? Also, can you tell us anything more about the siblings? How many were there, and were they boys, girls, or both?

Comment: I'm going to guess it was published in the late 90s or early 2000s. I read the books between 1997 and 2002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pulling my hair out trying to remember a book series today with exactly the scenario that you describe. I stumbled into this webpage while I was searching for info on it. Except I remember the series being much older - I read it from my primary school library at about 1992.

A few minutes ago I suddenly remembered the name of the alien invaders in the books - the Tektrons. Just did a search, and the book series was called **Counter Force**, with 2 books in the series: **Beware the Tektrons** and **Find the Tektrons**. Authors were George Erskine and Ian Cameron. Published in late 80s.

Hopefully this is what you're searching for.

**Edit: Being asked to provide more details about the series to see if they match the details in the question.**

It's been about 30 years since I read the books, so I can't recall the series in full detail. I remember that the books were set in near future, but can't remember when. In each book humans were building a different high tech complex that Tektrons were planning to take over and invade the world with. They lived in the electronics/electricity and I think (not entirely sure) that the Tektrons were subtly pushing humans to build each complex for them without the humans knowing. Each book was a race against time stealth mission for the teenagers to destroy the complex before it goes fully operational.

There were about 5 or 6 teenagers. The main family, whose father went into hiding, and their friends. No-one knows about the invasion except father and the kids. The father sends encrypted messages to his kids at start of each book to give them their mission to infiltrate the compound the aliens plan to take over, and provide them with tech to defeat the aliens. I think 2 of the teenagers were genius-level tech nerds who decipher the coded messages and could build some of their tech. I don't think the father appears in the books, he goes into hiding before 1st book starts.

Can't really recall any details about the kids and their personalities!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you give us a few details of these books to explain how they match the question?

Comment: This is it !!  Awesome. I've actually searched for Tektrons in the past but never got any good leads(at least not on the first page).